# How to hide navbar collapse when we click on outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing the issue in  when i click on the icon bar the drop down menu opens and then when i click on the another menu (Alumini menu ) ,the iconbar's drop down menu is not closed but both the alumini menu and the icon bars dropdown menu is viewed.I don't know why the iconbar's drop down menu is not closed while clicking the alumini menu.
The html code  for design is uploaded below.

```
<div class="join">
<!-- Nav Starts -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default container-fluid wrap">
  <div class="container pos-relative">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <ul class="new pull-left">
        <li class="old"> <a href="http://localhost/wordpress"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/skv-logo-100px.png"></img></a> </li>
        <li> <a class="navbar-brand create hidden-xs" href="http://localhost/wordpress">SKV Vidhyaashram</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <ul  class="nav navbar-nav navbar-main pull-left hidden-xs">
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-and-events/ ">News & Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/toppers-3/ ">Toppers</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/achievements2/">Achievements</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/isa-activities-2/">ISA Activities</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Alumni</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu alumni-menu">
            <li><a href="http://dev.seyali.com/alumni_demo/public/AlumniHome">Alumni Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://dev.seyali.com/alumni_demo/public/AllCommitteeMembers">Committee Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://dev.seyali.com/alumni_demo/public/AllGallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="http://dev.seyali.com/skvalumni/events.php">Events</a></li> -->
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="user-icon" href="http://dev.seyali.com/alumni_demo/public/login" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Login"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="quicklinkbar-toggle collapsed pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#quicklinkbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="quicklinkbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </button>
    </div>

<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""> About Us<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="">Chairman's Notes</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Mission & Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Principal's Notes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown list">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""> Academics<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="">CBSE Circular</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Academic Objectives</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CBSE & Afflitation</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Grades Prekg to X</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Innovative Teaching Methods</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Labs & Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Prekg,Juniorkg & Seniorkg</a></li>
            <li><a href="">School Terms & Curriculum</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown list1">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""> Beyond-Academics<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="">Co-curricular</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Extra-curricular</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Life at SKV</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown list2">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""> Sports & Games<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sports Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sports Facilities</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown list3">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""> Admission Fees<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Registration & Admission</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Entrance Examination</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fees & Payment</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown list4">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""> Gallery<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Image Gallery 2014-2015</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Image Gallery 2016-2017</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Video Gallery</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown list5">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""> Careers<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Working at SKV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Positions Vacant</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">General Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Apply Online</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
<div id="quicklinkbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a>News & Events</a></li>
        <li><a>Toppers</a></li>
        <li><a>Achievements</a></li>
        <li><a>ISA Activities</a></li>
        <li><a>Alumni</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- Nav Ends -->
```

And the image is attached below [image]

In above attached the two menus are apperaing , in that when i click on the icon bar drop down menu o[pens and again when i click on the alumini menu alumini menu opens but iconbars drop down menu is not closed.Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: check click on document, if menu is open && target is not menu, close menu

Comment: unfortunately, you will have to operate that `collapsed` class yourself, bootstrap doesn't have this as a built in feature

Comment: Nothing in the HTML controls the behavior of these mouseovers, you'll need to show some CSS or JS.